# Redis smembers command performance with 1k req/sec

Tags: nginx, lua, redis

I have about 120 000 records in the database.

The record example is: `categories:example.com = ['category_1', 'category_2', 'category_3']`

I have about 1k requests per second and for each request I call in nginx+lua

```
local categories, err = red:smembers("categories:"..clear_url)
```

Mostly requests has request time in access.log about 0-3ms but 2-4 requests per second has about 100-105ms.

Nginx+lua and redis db are on the same server and I use unix sock for connecting.
Load average is about 0,05

Please help me to find bottleneck.

Comment: Is there anything outstanding in Redis' SLOWLOG?

Comment: @ItamarHaber SLOWLOG is empty. If SLOWLOG is empty then this problem not with redis performance, correct?

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Is the connection pool properly sized? (btw, are you using lua-resty-redis or something else?)

Comment: @CristianGreco I use unix domain socket for connection. I thought that red:set_keepalive it is for tcp connection. I'm using lua-resty-redis.

Comment: @NikolayZavada The connection pooling works for the unix socket too. Please try to tune the pool size and other params using [these](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#check-list-for-issues) suggestions and let me know.

Comment: @CristianGreco I tried to use sample-bt-off-cpu for testing but I have the error `semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'scheduler' at <input>:28:7
        source: probe scheduler.cpu_on {
                      ^
semantic error: no match` and I don't know how to fix it. Maybe it is the problem with CPU because CPU usage is very low under load.

Comment: Did you try tuning the network params such as connection pooling, timeout and redis tcp backlog before digging into systemtap utilities (which may be hard to understand)?

Comment: Also, what happens if you change the number of nginx workers (both lower or higher)?